# Input File Hidden without choose the file

Tags: html

I have a condition where we have an input file, but the file is set by system..

```
<input type="file" hidden="" name="document_file" multiple="multiple" value=" url(C:\fakepath\PERTANYAAN.docx) norepeat">
```

but if I run the code above, the input file not contain the file, in this context "PERTANYAAN.docx".

What should I add to this input?

Comment: I can just guess that this will never work. I mean really, a hidden field which would randomly upload files from your hard drive? Security risk much?

Comment: actually I have an input file that is not hidden, so the user can choose which files to upload. then what I want is to move the selected file into the hidden input file

Answer (score 0):

As I already state in my comment, this is not working due to security reasons.

> It is important that a user agent not send any file that the user
> has    not explicitly asked to be sent. Thus, HTML interpreting agents
> are    expected to confirm any default file names that might be
> suggested    with .  Never have any
> hidden fields be    able to specify any file.

See [RFC1867 - Section 8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867#section-8) as reference.

Comment: actually I have an input file that is not hidden, so the user can choose which files to upload. then what I want is to move the selected file into the hidden input file

Comment: base64 encode it and make a hidden text variable out of it.